# Determining whether a given column in all rows of a file meets criteria

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

Let's say i have a file with below content.

```
ok     yes    bad
ok     yes    good
ok     yes    bad
ok     yes    good
ok     yes    bad
ok     yes    good
```

I need to write a shell script or awk program to search the whole 3rd column and if the whole column is good then print as "Everthing looks good" and incase if it finds anyone bad then print as "Things are not okay"

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Do it with a simple awk one-liner condition:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ok=1;} $3=="bad" { ok=0 } END { if (ok==0) {print "Things are not okay"} else { print "Everything looks good"} }' yourfile
```

`BEGIN` block initializes `ok` to 1 before file parsing starts. Default: all is ok unless bad is found.

Your file has natural space/tab separation, no need to tweak awk field separator: `$3` is directly the third field that we need. Just test if meets `bad` somewhere, and if so, cancel the ok flag.

`END` block is executed at the end of the file. Check `ok` and print relevant message.

Comment: The intent is to scan the whole file. You'd want to set a flag and print in the END block.

Comment: @jean: but it's printing multiple times. I want awk to search the entire column and if whole column has value "good" then it has to print only ONE time, in this case it's printing multiple times.

Comment: @suru1432002, note the edits -- it does that now.

Comment: I have fixed that thanks to Charles (the question was not that clear, I saw a brief similar answer popping up then disappearing)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: thanks for your quick response, I am new bee to awk can you please explain me the whole command

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm writing as I learned 15 years ago. I haved changed, tested and edited as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '$3=="bad"{f=1; exit} END{print (f ? "Things are not OK" : "Everything looks good")}' file
Things are not OK
```

The above sets a flag and `exist`s the main work loop (NOTE: `exit` doesn't exit the program, just the implicit loop that's reading the input, so then it takes you to the `END` section) the first time it finds "bad" so it's as efficient as possible and then in the END section it uses a ternary expression to print the relevant message based on that flag being set or not.

If you will be doing any text manipulation ever in your life, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition by Arnold Robbins to learn how to do it concisely, efficiently, robustly, and portably.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
awk '$3=="bad"{bad++} END { if (bad>0) print bad " bads found"; else print "all goods!"}' file
```